# Spark with Kotlin Tutorial from Github is not working

Tags: kotlin

i installed the tutorial project https://github.com/tipsy/spark-kotlin in the latest jetbrains community ide and started the code. I started the project, went to http://localhost:4567/ and i see 404 Not found in the chrome browser. In the console i see a std output of the user collection and messages like:

> "[qtp955940837-21] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The
>   requested route [/] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept:
>   [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8]"

I'm new spark and i don't know how to fix it. I'm running on java 10 right now.

thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer of tell me what you expected is missing in my answer....

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't browse http://localhost:4567. You should browse  http://localhost:4567/users.

According to the source code:

```
path("/users") {

    get("") { req, res ->
        jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(userDao.users)
    }

    get("/:id") { req, res ->
        userDao.findById(req.params("id").toInt())
    }

// .... blabla
```

There is no listener for `/`.